# How to cancel print jobs on network printer?

Tags: printing, network-printer

I want to cancel all the print jobs that were sent to certain network printer. 
I don't have the access to computer from which the jobs were sent.

Example: Jobs were sent to network printer from multiple computers.
After printer was disconected for service and put back after a week it started printing assigned jobs. I don't know from which computer there were sent - too many computers to bother about or they are off at the moment.

So can I somehow cancel printing jobs without accessing the computer? 
Is it possible to cancel jobs the printer itself?
All computers are with Windows 7 or 10.

Thanks

Comment: You mush have permission for to clear this printer's queue. If you have - do this clearing. You can do it even when the printer is off, even remotely.

Comment: Yes, I can clear the printer's queue remotely by connecting to computer that send jobs to printer. But the thing is that sometimes I don't have access to that computer (it's off) or that user is off for a week. Thanks for fast reply :)

Comment: You can do nothing when queue's host workstation is off.

Comment: *I don't know from which computer there were sent - too many computers to bother about or they are off at the moment.* Disable anonimous (guest) acces to the printer. Create separate account for each user who accesses this printer. And you will always know who was sent the job.

Comment: [windows - Jobs stuck in Print Queue on print server - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/150472/jobs-stuck-in-print-queue-on-print-server)

Comment: @DavidPostill: This link is for when the print server is a Windows computer. I think that in the poster's case, all computers connect directly to the printer, so there is no queue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, the network printer is being sent jobs from the network.
As there is no central print server, there is no unified print queue that can be
cleared.

You may use PowerShell to connect to a remote computer and delete all jobs in
the printer queue, using the command:

```
Get-Printer -ComputerName <SystemName>| Get-PrintJob | Remove-PrintJob
```

Note that if the remote computer is connected to another printer, local or remote,
this will also clear its queue.

Documentation: [Remove-PrintJob](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/remove-printjob?view=win10-ps).

Comment: You understood it right, there is no central printer server. I supposed there is no way to clear it from the printer, but since not having the printer server I got to ask :)

Comment: You can't clear it from the printer, as you don't have a way of knowing if an incoming job is new or old.